# JavaScript src onload

Tags: javascript, onload, src

Ok, I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
window.onload = function(){ 
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = 'jscript.js'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s); 
} </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.facebook.com/dragosgaftoneanu" 

onload = "alert('logged in')"
onerror="alert('not logged in)">

</script>
```

I want to execute the code from the first script at the onload of the second script. I have jscript.js where it is defined function().

Comment: None of that markup makes any sense, and I don’t think what you want is possible.

Comment: May I ask, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can figure out a better solution if you describe your task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

as what i understand, do you want to call the first js file using the second js file?

here is the code

in your file2.html you need to add the src of the first file

```
<script language="javascript" src='location'></script>

<script language="javascript">

 function init()
 {

   name();//call the function name. It's either in this file or in your first file
  }

</script>

<body onload="init()">
```